# How to pull in other columns into a select list with a conditional?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get multiple columns if a particular column passes a conditional Then I want to pull more data. For Example,

```
Select 
 co.id
,co.opp_id
,(IF co.opp_id NOT NULL THEN Opp.Col1 ,opp.Col2)
,customer.cust_num
From co LEFT OUTER JOIN opp on co.opp_id = opp.opp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer on co.cust_num = customer.cust_num
```

Pretty much that if the conditional passes, I would like the other information to be brought in. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You mean there will be a different result schema depending on the condition?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @VarunMehta Yes different results depending on the condition.

Comment: I think you want Dynamic SQL to accomplish this

Comment: @erickbarreat I dont think you can do this, You might need to write IF statement with the condition and select statements depending on your needs

Comment: @erickbarreat, are your conditional arguments dynamic? Please provide the sample data and your desired result to provide better answer.

Comment: I would suggest not changing the columns in your output based on the data. It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I have a stored Procedure which I am trying to pull in more information from. It is from a licensed software so legally I can not share the code here. 

But it is an estimate response form where it gets customer, Opportunity (opp) , and customer order (co) . I need to add more tables and parameters if the co.opp_id is not null.

Comment: I would suggest using a left join and wrapping those columns with case expression. You can't change the columns on a row by row level which is what is sounds like you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SeanLange Correct, I should also mention that this query is wrapped in a cursor, so it is technically on a row by row level I am not 100% savvy with cursors ?  Using coalesce might be the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: Ouch...using a cursor for a query is almost never a good approach. Especially if you are just retrieving data is could surely be done without a RBAR approach. coalesce or isnull is probably not going to be quite what you want here.

Comment: And using a cursor on a dynamic column-set is definitely something to stay away from.  Cursors aren't as terrible as everyone says - there is a time and place for them - but if at all possible, they should be avoided because they're inherently inefficient.  But, like I said, sometimes they're a necessary evil.

Comment: @erickbarreat Good job on being attentive and responsive to the comments here.  It helps people answer your questions as best and quickly as possible.

Comment: @StanShaw , This is how the stored procedure for this report was written for this software. Got to make way with what you got. lol. 
I think the CASE statement might just be the only route here. I will try it out and give you guys an update. Also no problem, I find that if you ask a question, you should always be attentive to the people giving you feedback as a courtesy.

Comment: It's not possible to have a single query return a result set that has extra columns in some rows and not in others.  The extra columns can be NULL in some rows, but they must always be there.  Even after all the comments, it's not clear to me if this is what you need for some reason, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is use a case statement:

```
Select 
 co.id
,co.opp_id
,CASE WHEN co.opp_id IS NOT NULL THEN Opp.Col1 ELSE NULL END AS [Col1]
 ,CASE WHEN opp.Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN opp.Col2 ELSE NULL END AS [Col2]
,customer.cust_num
From co LEFT OUTER JOIN opp on co.opp_id = opp.opp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer on co.cust_num = customer.cust_num
```

Note, that with this approach, you will always have the same output columns.  And, in this example, the `CASE` statement is superfluous because you're replacing `NULL` with `NULL` - however you get the idea.  You could say:

`WHEN co.opp_id is NULL THEN [Some Other Column] ELSE co.opp_id`

or something along those lines, but like the comments suggest, DON'T change your output columns, since you may build apps/reports based on the output - and you don't want those extra layers of maintenance and unpredictability.

Comment: This makes sense. I figured it would have to be this way, but I thought there had to be a more dynamic approach instead of for each column I need to have a case statement.

Comment: You CAN use a dynamic approach, however I strongly recommend against it for the stated reasons.  You want a consistent output from your queries - it makes future integration easier - and it makes the result predictable so end-users know what they're getting.